# CLI tool that lists the DLL files that are mentioned in the Imports section of a Windows PE executable?

Tags: import, command-line-interface, portable-executable

I am looking for a CLI tool that will list all of the DLL files referenced in the Import section of a Windows executable file. Back in the day, Windows shipped with a GUI tool called [QuickView](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickView) that provided this information. However, I need a CLI-based application that will provide this information and preferrably a free / open-source application if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking this question and doing some searching, I concluded that the easiest way to get a program like this was to write one. So I did.

The end result was a program named PEImportList (released under the MIT license). It does nothing more than open a PE executable (x86 only at the moment) and read the import data, printing a list of DLL names to the console.

The code will run on any platform and can be found in this single file here:

> https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/5b25da083ad5c6557e89

Simply invoke the program by passing the executable as a parameter. If you want *only* the DLL names printed, then stick the `-l` option in front of the executable parameter.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, `dumpbin` tool from Microsoft could help. It is shipped with Microsoft Visual C++. The details are in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Try `dumpbin /IMPORTS <pe_file_to_analyze>`.

I guess, the tool is not open source, however. But if it is included in Microsoft Visual C++ Express (not sure about that), you can get it for free.